# I am not sure how to convey this

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-request

> The media affects the public opinion in order to change election
>   results **in favour of businessmen \ to the advantage of businessmen** who in return, support the media
>   financially.

I want to say that election results are changed to make businessmen or their allies win the election, and as a result, they use their political power to flourish their businesses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest something like this:

> Media can affect public opinion, such that election results are skewed in favour of businesses that support the media financially.

Hope that helps,

Alan.

Answer (score 0):

The second phrase 'to advantage of businessmen' is more frequent in the usage of media. That is why, there are many examples with it from the political newspapers and books on the Internet.